# What is the correct way to print out multiple data using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

In a previous question I was told that if I want to store multiple languages for a user then it is best to have a separate table mapping languages and users together.
That makes sense because it is a classic many-to-many relationship so that is what I have done.

My question now is what query can I write that will concatenate all the language names for each user and then display that as a table?

I made the following (is it correct?):

```
CREATE TABLE language (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name char(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE)

CREATE TABLE user (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name char(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE)

CREATE TABLE user_language (
id_user INT REFERENCES user(id),
id_lang INT REFERENCES language(id) )
```

I then inserted 3 test users, 7 test languages and inserted 9 pairs into the user_language table. Now I want to print a concatenated list of the languages each user speaks next to the users names using only one MySQL query and I have no idea how to do that.
So for example I would like to see

```
User    |   Languages
--------|---------------
Bob     | English, French
Alex    | Spanish, Portuguese
Ivan    | Russian, English, German
```

Any ideas? Am I even on the right track?

**EDIT**

I am aware of the JOIN function so printing the list out as a set of individual pairs is not my intention. I specifically want to concatenate the languages for each user without resorting to writing a loop in a script (it would be in PHP in my case).
I thought there might be some way of writing a subquery and using the CONCATENATE function that might be able to help me...? Am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at using an INNER JOIN for this.  Essentially, the JOIN is going to take a look at the IDs in each field and then match data together for entries that have matching IDs.

Consider the following SQL query:

```
SELECT user.*, language.name FROM user
INNER JOIN user_language ON user.id = user_language.id_user
INNER JOIN language ON user_language.id_lang = language.id;
```

Order of the INNER JOINs is important; the first thing we need to do is be able to reference language IDs relative to the user ID.  The first INNER JOIN is going to give each user a list of language IDs which the user can speak.  The second is going to map that language ID that was assigned to the user to a name.

However, the above will not return them in a comma-separated list.  Instead, you'll get something like this:

```
name    |    language
-------------------------
bob     |   English
bob     |   Dutch
Sally   |   English
Sally   |   Spanish
Sally   |   German
```

You'll have to do some post processing to put the data into a comma-separated list.  Doing so in almost any language should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I might accept this answer if it turns out that really is the only way to do it. I was sure there would be some clever way to get MySQL to do the concatenation for me without having to resort to writing a loop in a script.

Comment: So, after much posting someone else answered my question correctly in another post. However your answer got me close enough so Ive marked it as correct.  The command I was looking for was GROUP_CAT. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, b.name from language a, user b where id_user = b.id and id_lang = a.id;
```

Comment: I believe User's map to language through the user_language table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a completely valid design.

```
SELECT user.name, language.name FROM user INNER JOIN user_language ON(user.id = user_language.id_user) INNER JOIN language ON(language.id_lang = language.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name as user, l.name as language 
    FROM USER u 
    INNER JOIN user_language ul ON u.id = ul.id_user
    INNER JOIN LANGUAGE l ON ul.id_lang = l.id;
```

Comment: using your code the final query is :SELECT user, GROUP_CONCAT(language SEPARATOR ', ') FROM (
SELECT u.name as user, l.name as language 
    FROM USER u 
    INNER JOIN user_language ul ON u.id = ul.id_user
    INNER JOIN LANGUAGE l ON ul.id_lang = l.id) AS joined
GROUP BY user

Comment: Very nice. I hadn't heard of GROUP_CONCAT before, thanks for sharing the solution